# how to increase date concerning a working week?

Tags: java, date

I have a date in java, and I would like to add a certain amount of working time to it.

However, it should consider a working week.

```
8 Hours days (8:00 to 16:00),
```

and

```
no work on weekends (Saturday/Sunday).
```

So I have a `Date object` giving the `current time`. I also have a `double`, which are the minutes to be added to that date. What would be the best way of doing this?

`I'm using Java 8.`

Some examples:

Working on the same day:

```
Date date = new Date(2000, 1, 1, 8, 0); //so first of jan, 8:00. Let's assume this is a monday.
double minutes = 4 * 60;
Date newDate = addWorkingTime(date, minutes);
// newDate should be the same day, 12:00
```

Working over multiple days:

```
Date date = new Date(2000, 1, 1, 14, 0); //so first of jan, 14:00. Let's assume this is a monday.
double minutes = 4 * 60;
Date newDate = addWorkingTime(date, minutes);
// newDate should be the next day, 10:00
// 2 hours on the first day, the next two hours of work on the next.
```

Working over a weekend:

```
Date date = new Date(2000, 1, 5, 14, 0); //so fifth of jan, 14:00. Let's assume this is a friday.
double minutes = 8 * 60;
Date newDate = addWorkingTime(date, minutes);
// newDate should be the next monday, 14:00
// 2 hours on the first day, the next six hours of work the next monday.
```

Thanks!

Comment: Can you give an example of `Date` object, and what output you would get for adding some example *minutes*?

Comment: Of course, I'll add it to the question.

Comment: Voila, added the examples ;) I hope they're clear enough.

Comment: @TheOddler if you are on Java 8 you may as well use the new Java Time API - but I don't think you will find a way other than adding the minutes up to the end of the day then adding one day, checking if it's a week end etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this method:

```
public static LocalDateTime addWorkingMinutes(LocalDateTime date, long minutes) {
    if (date.getHour() < 8) {
      // Working day hasn't started. Reset date to start of this working day
      date = date.withHour(8).withMinute(0).withSecond(0);
    }

    // Take care of weekends
    if (date.getDayOfWeek() == DayOfWeek.SATURDAY) {
      date = date.plusDays(2);
    } else if (date.getDayOfWeek() == DayOfWeek.SUNDAY) {
      date = date.plusDays(1);
    }

    LocalDateTime endOfCurrentWorkingDay = date.withHour(16).withMinute(0).withSecond(0);

    // Get minutes from date to endOfCurrentWorkingDay
    long minutesCovered = ChronoUnit.MINUTES.between(date, endOfCurrentWorkingDay);
    if (minutesCovered > minutes) {
      // If minutesCovered covers the minutes value passed, that means result is the same working
      // day. Just add minutes and return
      return date.plusMinutes(minutes);
    } else {
      // Calculate remainingMinutes, and then recursively call this method with next working day
      long remainingMinutes = minutes - minutesCovered;
      return addWorkingMinutes(endOfCurrentWorkingDay.plusDays(1).withHour(8), remainingMinutes);
    }
}
```

tested with your sample input, and some other inputs on my end, considering weekends.

Note: I'm using Java 8 DateTime API, since you're already on Java 8, there shouldn't be any excuse to still use `Date`.